# Deployed Vue app managed with 'webpack-simple' doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm working on my first `Vue` app, which uses the `Moment` library and `Firebase` (if that matters). I use default `Webpack simple`. To deploy the app I did `npm run build`.

But when opening directly `index.html` (the app is deployed [here](http://fabricepallaud.com/timelog/)) I get `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"` error message and the app doesn't work at all as a result.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue since there's no more information that this in `DevTools`...

[image]

Any idea about what I can do next?

[App source code](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/timelog/tree/dev)

Comment: Is your public folder set up as 'public', because it might need to point to 'dist'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first **forward slashes** of all your assets path.
It should fix your problem.

```
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script> // No!
<script src="dist/build.js"></script> // Yes!
```

Vue adds it by default during the build process, in order to make your assets relative to the root folder.

Comment: Thanks! Strange though, when removing the slash, the build now works but the dev version still works as well: why does Webpack add it in the first place then? Any idea?